stop fastify from stripping out null values in json response: is that configurable/programmable?
If inside my route handler, I return a json object like this:
return { items: findItemById(idParam) }

it works fine, as long as findItemById() actually finds something.
When it doesn't, I'm essentially creating a response payload like { items: undefined } or maybe { items: null }, and fastify seems to be stripping out the attribute entirely and returning { }.
While I could write my own checks for this (I actually would like to return { items: [] } in such cases), I just wondered: is there a setting that automatically takes care of that? Or a setting which switches off the suppression of falsey values? Thx.

I have this same issue, how would you add your own checks?
